# Can't sign macOS app for Direct Distribution

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm trying to distribute my macOS app from Xcode 15.1 for Direct Distribution. When I try to do this in the Xcode organizer, I get:

```
There is a problem with the request entity
You already have a current Developer ID Application Managed (With Kext) certificate or a pending certificate request.
```

and

```
No profiles for '<redacted bundle ID>' were found
Xcode couldn't find any Developer ID provisioning profiles matching '< redacted bundle ID>'.
```

Xcode is set to manage the signing, so it should be creating all that. I can't find anything online giving me a clue about how to fix this (or even that anyone else has encountered this problem).

Comment: Do not make comments about votes. Voters are anonymous and are not here to hear you. So you're just talking to the air, blowing off steam. That's pointless.

Comment: I'm not here to justify how the site works. If you have questions about that, ask on Meta (if reading the docs doesn't help).

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why the simple flow fails, but I was able to notarize and distribute my app by using a "Custom" flow. I also had to manually create a Developer ID Provisioning Profile for my app, and download that in Xcode’s Account settings.

In Custom, answer each step with the following:

1. Method: Developer ID
2. Destination: Upload
3. Re-sign: Manually
4. Select certificate and profiles: select your Developer ID Certificate (which I had to create in the Developer Portal), and your Developer ID Provisioning Profile for your app (which I also had to create in the Portal).
5. Click Upload
6. Wait for Apple to notarize it (should be a few minutes).
7. Distribute that archive again once it’s “Ready to Distribute.”
8. Follow the same steps as above, but it will short-circuit most of them and go straight to Export.
9. Choose a location for the exported app. This one should be distributable (I’m still awaiting verification that someone else can actually install this).

(After all this, I tried the simple Direct Distribution method, and it still doesn’t work.)